# Vue-2 Jest-24 running test error, SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, ts-jest, vue-ssr

Errors in running Jest tests for Vue 2

Hi all, i'm having trouble running tests for Vue 2.6 app. (i use sever-renderer)
I tried to write test with my Router usage, which uses ts modules...

my test file:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import createRouter from '~/routers/index'; // CreateRouter not work
import ShoppingSarchPage from '@/pages/shopping/search/index.ts';

const router = createRouter();

describe('Router tests', () => {
  test('Search page renders correctly', () => {
    // simple test
    const wrapper = mount(ShoppingSarchPage, {
      router,
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.shopping-search-page').exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

~/router/index

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import configApp from '~/config';
import { makeLocation, Location } from '~/routers/define.ts';

Vue.use(Router);

import RouterServices, { Services } from '~/routers/services';
import RouterShopping, { Shopping } from '~/routers/shopping';
import RouterAuto, { Auto } from '~/routers/auto';
import RouterTech, { Tech } from '~/routers/tech/index.ts';
import RouterHtml from '~/routers/html';

// Exporting page names for navigation in components
export const Pages = {
  Home: 'page-home',
  Help: 'page-help',
  Contact: 'page-contact',
  Tariff: 'page-tariff',
  Terms: 'page-terms',
  Privacy: 'page-privacy',
  Favorites: 'page-favorites',
  error404: 'page-404',
  Services,
  Shopping,
  Auto,
  Tech,
};

export default () => {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: configApp.routeBaseUrl,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/404',
        name: Pages.error404,
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "other" */ '~/pages/404.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: '/:lang(\\w{2}|\\w{2}-\\w{2})?/:city?',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "other" */ '~/pages/base.vue'),
        props: (route): Location => ({ location: makeLocation(route) }),
        children: [
          ...RouterServices,
          ...RouterShopping,
          ...RouterAuto,
          ...RouterTech,
          ...RouterHtml,
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        redirect: { name: Pages.error404 },
      },
    ],
  });
};
```

Here are all the configurations below

Vue 2.6.12
Vue-router 3.5
Node 12.22.12
Typescript 4
Jest 24

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-ssr",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node banner && node --max-old-space-size=8192 --inspect index",
    "worker": "npm run build:worker",
    "start": "node banner && node --max-old-space-size=8192 index",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm:build:*\"",
    "build:client": "webpack --config build/webpack/client.js",
    "build:server": "webpack --config build/webpack/server.js",
    "build:worker": "webpack --config build/webpack/worker.js",
    "build:sprite": "node build/svg-sprite.js",
    "deploy-dev": "cross-env TARGET_DEPLOY=dev npm run build",
    "start-dev": "cross-env TARGET_DEPLOY=dev npm run start",
    "deploy-staging": "cross-env TARGET_DEPLOY=staging npm run build",
    "start-staging": "cross-env TARGET_DEPLOY=staging npm run start",
    "deploy-prod": "cross-env TARGET_DEPLOY=prod npm run build",
    "start-prod": "cross-env TARGET_DEPLOY=prod npm run start",
    "predev": "rimraf dist && npm run build:worker",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.22.12",
    "npm": ">=6.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "1.3.0",
    "@sentry/node": "6.19.7",
    "@sentry/tracing": "6.19.7",
    "@sentry/vue": "6.19.7",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "3.2.8",
    "@turf/turf": "5.1.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "debug": "4.3.1",
    "dexie": "3.0.3",
    "imask": "6.4.3",
    "ismobilejs": "1.1.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "2.4.1",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.25",
    "node-cache": "5.1.2",
    "nouislider": "15.2.0",
    "query-string": "7.0.0",
    "runtypes": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "2.2.0",
    "sortablejs": "1.13.0",
    "swiper": "6.7.5",
    "text-clipper": "2.1.0",
    "throttle-debounce": "2.1.0",
    "tiny-date-picker": "3.2.8",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "twilio-client": "1.9.7",
    "twilio-video": "2.7.1",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "vue": "2.6.12",
    "vue-drag-resize": "2.0.3",
    "vue-i18n": "8.27.1",
    "vue-mapbox": "0.4.1",
    "vue-meta": "2.4.0",
    "vue-no-ssr": "1.1.1",
    "vue-plyr": "7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "3.5.2",
    "vue-server-renderer": "2.6.12",
    "vue2-datepicker": "3.9.1",
    "vue2-perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.0",
    "vuex": "3.1.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "5.0.0",
    "workbox-background-sync": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-core": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-expiration": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-range-requests": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-routing": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-strategies": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-streams": "6.5.1",
    "workbox-window": "6.5.1",
    "zenscroll": "4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.11.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.11.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/register": "7.11.5",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^5.9.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "2.4.0",
    "@types/sortablejs": "1.10.6",
    "@types/throttle-debounce": "2.1.0",
    "@types/twilio-video": "2.7.1",
    "@types/uuid": "8.3.0",
    "@types/vue2-datepicker": "3.3.1",
    "@types/workbox-background-sync": "4.3.2",
    "@types/workbox-broadcast-update": "4.3.1",
    "@types/workbox-core": "4.3.1",
    "@types/workbox-expiration": "4.3.1",
    "@types/workbox-range-requests": "4.3.0",
    "@types/workbox-routing": "4.3.1",
    "@types/workbox-strategies": "4.3.1",
    "@types/workbox-streams": "4.3.0",
    "@types/workbox-window": "4.3.4",
    "@types/zenscroll": "4.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.1.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.16.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "5.1.0",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.12.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "22.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "7.0.1",
    "express": "4.18.1",
    "express-winston": "4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "2.0.2",
    "jest-transform-stub": "2.0.0",
    "jsdoc": "3.6.2",
    "jsdoc-vue": "1.0.0",
    "kouto-swiss": "1.1.0",
    "memory-fs": "0.4.1",
    "minami": "1.2.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.6.0",
    "null-loader": "2.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "polka": "1.0.0-next.3",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.3.2",
    "pretty-error": "2.2.0-rc.1",
    "pug": "2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "1.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "sass": "1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "sass-resources-loader": "2.1.1",
    "serialize-javascript": "5.0.1",
    "serve-static": "1.14.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "9.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-rational-order": "0.1.2",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "3.3.0",
    "stylelint-processor-arbitrary-tags": "0.1.0",
    "stylelint-processor-html": "1.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.6.1",
    "svg-sprite": "1.5.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "8.0.5",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "vue-class-component": "7.2.6",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "7.1.1",
    "vue-jest": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "vue-loader": "15.9.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "9.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.12",
    "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "vuex-class": "0.3.2",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-command": "0.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.25.0",
    "webpackbar": "3.2.0",
    "winston": "3.7.2",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "4.7.1"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
  ],
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "exclude": [".git", ".idea", "assets", "dist", "docs", "node_modules"],
  "include": ["**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "incremental": false /* Enable incremental compilation */,
    "target": "ES5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom", "WebWorker"],
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "." /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./dist/build-info" /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */,
    "allowJs": true,
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    "importHelpers": false /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */,
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": false /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */,
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '.',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
};
```

Guys, please share your guesses and possible solutions <3
What could be wrong, a different version in some packages, or some packages should match in versions? o_O

error:

[testing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cqpl.jpg)

Comment: The issue is likely in one of your .vue file. Can you share that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely related to you using a shorthand template statement in your .vue component. Vue 2.x has an issue with using pug and shorthand template statements when running tests (See: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/175)

From the error, it may be in your map component. There are two options on resolving your issue.

First one is as described in the GitHub, adding the following to your `jest.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  globals: {
    'vue-jest': {
      pug: { doctype: 'html' }
    }
  }
}
```

The second option, in case the above does not work (which it did not for me as there is a bug in some package I cannot resolve) is to not use shorthand template tags.

Try finding a statement that looks like `template(#someslot)` and replace it with `template(#someslot="")` or `template(someslot="")`.

Comment: Thank you, it's weird why I haven't seen this issue before... 